# text analysis - looking to remove lowercase words from my corpus. Can I use gsub? Using tm_map to clean-up

Tags: r, corpus

I'm looking to clean-up a corpus to find proper names.  How would i remove all lowercase words?  removeWords? gsub?

```
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, removePunctuation)
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, removeNumbers)
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("SMART"))

doc.corpus <-tm_map(doc.corpus, removeWords, lower)  ****something like this?****

inspect(doc.corpus[8])
```

Comment: Maybe `tolower`?

Comment: Guess, Op wants to remove all the lower case words!

Comment: @Nelson R. Jatel  Can you accept the answer if it was helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Depending on what your desired output is, you might have to reorder the replacements. In the following example, e.g., dots are removed from the abbreviation "U.S." which gives "U S", only two separate letters. If you want to keep such abbreviations you will have to adapt your regex.

```
library(tm)
data(crude)
corp <- crude

corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(gsub), pattern="(?<=\\s|^)([a-z]+)(?=\\s|$|\\W)", replacement = " ", perl=T)
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(gsub), pattern="\\d|\\W", replacement = " ", perl=T)
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(gsub), pattern="\\s+", replacement = " ", perl=T)

inspect(corp[[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
teststring <- "aaa Bbb ccc Ddd eee Fff"
trimws(gsub("\\b[a-z]+\\b", "", teststring))
#[1] "Bbb  Ddd  Fff"
```

Above `gsub` function removes all lowercase words. So, you can use this `gsub` function in your code as below:

```
removeLowerCase <- function(x) trimws(gsub("\\b[a-z]+\\b", "", x))
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, content_transformer(removeLowerCase))
```

Comment: @ulfelder Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the answers as OP asked.